# Logical Replication/Foreign Data Wrapper Connectivity between Two Aurora Serverless Databases (PostgreSQL 10.7)

Tags: replication, postgresql-10, aws-aurora

I have two Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless databases running in the same region and have PostgreSQL version 10.7. I'm wondering if logical replication is available? The official [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html) say that it's possible for Aurora PostgreSQL, but nothing specifically about Serverless databases.

It times out when I tried to run this command with the right credentials:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION testsub CONNECTION 
   'host=publisher-cluster-writer-endpoint port=5432 dbname=db-name user=user password=password' 
   PUBLICATION testpub;
```

I also struggle to have connectivity set up for Foreign Data Wrapper between two Serverless PostgreSQL databases.